# Change Owner button is not visible to System Admin

Tags: page-layout

Does anyone know why the Change Owner is not visible to System Admin? I already add it to the page layout. Thanks for answering.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using LEX flexipage. LEX quick actions are controlled from `Mobile & Lightning Actions` section on the layout, if you don't have `Dynamic Actions` enabled for it. Add `Change Owner` quick action from that section. `Buttons` section is controlling buttons in Classic Design.